# VB 2010 database search

Tags: database, vb.net, search

I want to create a VB 2010 program that searches a database for records where the value in the column "Amount" is >= from some value (10 for example).

I use this code to search for records where "Amount" is equal to a value:

```
Table1DataGridView.DataSource = Me.Your_DatabaseDataSet.Table1.Select("Amount like '10'")
```

But I need code that searches for records with a value >= 10, something like this:

```
Table1DataGridView.DataSource = Me.Your_DatabaseDataSet.Table1.Select("Amount >= '10'")
```

But this code finds records with an amount of "5.89", which is not >= 10.

Comment: It looks like the "Amount" column in your database is defined as a string when clearly it should be a number. Comparing strings, "5.89" is indeed greater than "10". If you make the Amount column an appropriate type, you should use 10 instead of '10' i n your Select statement.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Works perfect! :)